# Irregular sample frequency to regular sample frequency in Python

Tags: python, transformation, frequency

Example:

```
x1 = [0.0, 0.3, 0.8, 1.1]

y1 = [5, 6 , 4, 1]

period = 0.4
```

To:

```
x2 = [0.0, 0.4, 0.8, 1.2]

y2 = [...,..,..,..]
```

Of course this will be an estimation. Tried different things with no luck. The sample frequency is very high, so some down sampling is not a problem.

Comment: Could you post those things you tried?

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html and something with grid transformation

Comment: @user3411641 that's a documentation, not what you've tried. Post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> y1 = np.array([5, 6 , 4, 1])
>>> x1 = np.array([0.0, 0.3, 0.8, 1.1])
>>> period = 0.4

>>> x2 = period * np.arange(len(x1)) 
>>> x2
array([ 0. ,  0.4,  0.8,  1.2])

>>> np.interp(x2, x1, y1)
array([ 5. ,  5.6,  4. ,  1. ])
```